How to separate type deduction from function parameter declaration?
I have measured a significant speedup in my application if my function foo accepts primitive types by value instead of by universal (forwarding) reference. The speedup is lost however, if non-primitive types are not passed by universal reference. If foo was accepting a fixed number of arguments, this would do the trick:
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
requires (!std::is_scalar_v<std::decay_t<T>>)
auto foo(T&&){
    std::puts("pass by universal reference");
}

template <typename T>
requires std::is_scalar_v<std::decay_t<T>>
auto foo(T){
    std::puts("pass by value");
}

int main(){
    foo(42);  // pass by value
    foo(std::string{"hello"}); // pass by universal reference
    
    return 0;
}

However, the problem is that foo accepts a template parameter pack, and some parameters might be primitives while others might not. Thus, foo would have to deduce parameter types first and then, if they are not primitives, turn them into universal references. If foo was a class template, this could be achieved using deduction guides:
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
using MaybeRef =
    std::conditional_t<std::is_scalar_v<std::decay_t<T>>, std::decay_t<T>, T&&>;

#include <tuple>
template <typename... Ts>
struct Foo {
    
    Foo(Ts...) {
        static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::tuple_element_t<0, std::tuple<MaybeRef<Ts>...>>, int>);
        static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::tuple_element_t<1, std::tuple<MaybeRef<Ts>...>>, std::string&>);
        std::puts("passed");
    }
};

template <typename... Ts>
Foo(Ts&&...) -> Foo<MaybeRef<Ts>...>;

int main(){
    std::string str = "hello";
    Foo{42, str};

    return 0;
}

However, I do not know how to achieve the same for my function foo.
Is this even possible and how?

Your constructor could be just Foo(Ts... args) since the deduction guide has already made Ts... to be correct. You could just pretend that the class Foo is a function and do what the function is supposed to do in the constructor I guess?

Side node: what you have is not a forwarding reference, try with int i = 42; foo(i);.

Unrelated I think template <class T>
using MaybeRef = std::conditional_t<std::is_scalar_v<std::remove_cvref_t<T>>, std::remove_cvref_t<T>, T&&>; would be better for the scalars.

@TedLyngmo or combo of template <typename T>auto foo(T&& a) -> std::enable_if_t<!std::is_scalar_v<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(a)>>>  and template <typename T> requires std::is_scalar_v<T> auto foo(T). Whatever floats one's boat ;)

@alagner I don't see that working with a parameter pack though.

@TedLyngmo @alagner Yes, I have made a few mistakes in the rush. I have corrected them now, so please re-evaluate your remarks. Also, I know I could theoretically use class constructor as a function, but that would be very weird on the client side. I am not sure if I would be willing to do that. Also, if foo was actually some other class' constructor, that would not be possible, especially if that other class already has a different template parameter pack.

"I could theoretically use class constructor as a function, but that would be very weird on the client side." How is it weird? You can even has conversion operator for return type :-)

@Jarod42 If foo is actually a constructor of some class (for example Bar), I do not see how could this trick be used. Or?

It's not possible to do this in current C++, but there are a number of relevant proposals:

Herb Sutter's unpublished D0708 proposes (among other things) to add the in keyword, which would tell the compiler to declare the parameter as either by-value or by-reference depending on which would be more efficient.
Gašper Ažman et al. propose a more general mechanism called computed deduction in an also unpublished paper, D1107, which basically does exactly what you ask: to "separate type deduction from function parameter declaration".
Most recently, there is P2998 by James Touton, which would allow implementing your desired feature in library, since it would bring deduction guides into play when calling a function template.


Interesting. If this is currently not possible, what would be the next best thing?

@lobelk Well, most people just use forwarding references. It's quite rare to be in a situation where, in the grand scheme of things, the performance penalty will really hurt you.

@lobelk In extreme situations, you could force the user to specify the signature: example. This is of course very user-unfriendly, but if performance if of the utmost importance, it may be an option.
